# Displaying values in recyclerview (based on boolean value) returns same result for all items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, boolean-expression

I have a recyclerview with a lot of items. I use adapter to populate the recyclerview from server, i.e. name, date, time, and so on, and it works OK.

Only issue I have is when I try and ***populate it based on a boolean value***. When I try to add ***image star*** (for favourites option), and when I try to set ***is closed*** text (for active option), I always get all items with the "favourite icon" and "is closed" message.

For example, what I am trying to do when the working hours are returning active as false is like this:

```
if (!restaurant.getActive()) {
    holder.isClosed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Boolean works just fine when I am setting it from a *RestaurantDescriptionActivity*, it saves and updates on server as it should, and it also returns the correct value, so I am not sure where my mistake could be.

I am returning values for boolean like this in my RestaurantModel:

```
@SerializedName("favourites")
private boolean isFavourite;
@SerializedName("active")
private boolean active;
----
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {

    parcel.writeString(thumbnailUrl);
    parcel.writeString(dateTime);
    parcel.writeString(id);
    parcel.writeValue(comments_enabled);
    // I TRIED WRITING BOOLEAN TO PARCEL IN TWO WAYS, AS SHOWN BELOW
    parcel.writeValue(isFavourite);
    parcel.writeInt(active ? 1 : 0);
}

//// UPDATED PART
protected restaurant(Parcel in) {
   ...
    isFavourite = (Boolean) in.readValue(Boolean.class.getClassLoader());
    active = Boolean.parseBoolean(in.readString());   
}
//// UPDATED PART

public boolean getActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}
```

Adapter:

```
class restaurantsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView restaurantName, date, time, isClosed;
    ImageView thumbNail, isFavourite;

    restaurantsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        thumbNail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        isFavourite = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIsFavourite);
        restaurantName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantNameIcon);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        isClosed= itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantIsClosed);
    }
}

public restaurantsAdapter(List<restaurant> restaurantList, Context context) {
    this.restaurantItems = restaurantList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public restaurantsAdapter.restaurantsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row_restaurant, parent, false);

    return new restaurantsViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(restaurantsAdapter.restaurantsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // getting restaurant data for the row
    restaurant restaurant = restaurantItems.get(position);

    holder.restaurantName.setText(restaurant.getrestaurantName());
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(restaurant.getDateTime(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    String formattedDate = ldt.format(getLocalizedDateFormatter(Locale.getDefault()));

    holder.date.setText(formattedDate);
    //holder.date.setText(convertDate(restaurant.getDateTime())); //string dobiti u formatu, pretvoriti ga u localized i podijeliti na dva dijela
    holder.time.setText(convertTime(restaurant.getDateTime()));
    holder.isFavourite.clearColorFilter();
    if (!restaurant.getActive()) {
        holder.isClosed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (restaurant.getIsFavourite()) {
        holder.isFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_icon_star_ppdcolor);
    }

}
```

Comment: may be you are getting irestaurant.getActive() always false from server

Comment: @YahyaMukhtar No, I am getting the correct results when I open my RestaurantDescriptionActivity (the activity where I can view a single item opened from recyclerview), I always get the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to code else part inside RecyclerView item otherwise it will repopulate its previous view state.

```
if (!restaurant.getActive()) {
    holder.isClosed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else{
    holder.isClosed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

if (restaurant.getIsFavourite()) {
    holder.isFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_icon_star_ppdcolor);
} else{
    holder.isFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_icon_when_not_favourite);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kunu, I will try this tonight and let you know (hopefully by accepting your answer :) ).

Comment: During debugging I always get false in my adapter, although almost all of them are true, and when I open single restaurantActivity I get the correct value. Could this be due to parcel? I have updated my code.

Comment: I don't think parcel will do such thing. Check whether you are updating your RecyclerView data set when the value changed.

Answer (score 1):

make interface for the favourite click event and set that record value as true in main activity used below code ...

```
onItemClickListner onItemClickListner;


public interface onItemClickListner{
    void onItemClick(restaurant restaurantobj); // you can pass or object or value to need to access in recycler view activity.
}
public void setOnItemClickListner(RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner onItemClickListner) {
    this.onItemClickListner = onItemClickListner;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (!restaurant.getActive()) {
        holder.isClosed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else{
        holder.isClosed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (restaurant.getIsFavourite()) {
        holder.isFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_icon_star_ppdcolor);
    } else{
        holder.isFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_icon_when_not_favourite);
    }
    holder.isFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClickListner.onItemClick(restaurant);
        }
    });
 }
```

and after when you define adapter object in mainactivity that used below code ...

```
adpater.setOnItemClickListner(new RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(restaurant restaurantobj) {
            restaurantobj.setActive(true);
            restaurantList.add(restaurantobj);
            adpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I will take a look at this tonight and let you know. Thanks for detailed answer.

Comment: I do not want to add onClick here, only show/hide icon, or text on the recyclerview item. During debugging I always get false in my adapter, although almost all of them are true, and when I open single restaurantActivity I get the correct value. Could this be due to parcel? I have updated my code.